# react-native-vector-icons: Using FontAwesome

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

I am trying to use FontAwesome icons in my react-native app using this library `react-native-vector-icons`. I have followed the installation process (npm install, link, updating my gradle.properties...)
Then in my code I import the Icon like this:

```
const Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome');
```

And I use it in my render method:

```
<Button>
  <Icon name='home' />                        
</Button>
```

Unfortunately at runtime, this blows up with this error:

[image]

How can I use Fontawesome icons in my react-native app?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `import` instead:

`import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting an error when I do that from typescript:
"could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'".

Comment: Thanks. Removing the "noImplicitAny" option from my tsconfig.json. And now it is working.